# Is the usage of the word "BUT" in this sentence correct?

Tags: grammar, sentence

Please consider the following sentence:

> I am not just doing my job, **but** I am making a difference

is the sentence grammatically correct?

Should I add the word *also* in the second clause?

> I am not just doing my job, **but** I am **also** making a difference

Or is there something else to be done with it?

Edit: what about the *just* used in the sentence.. should it be *only* instead?

So, which of the following is the most accurate:

> 1. I am not **only** doing my job, but I am **also** making a difference
> 2. I am not **just** doing my job, but I am **also** making a difference
> 3. I am not **just** doing my job, but I am making a difference
> 4. I am not **only** doing my job, but I am making a difference

Comment: Yes it's better with "also".  It would be even better with a semicolon or an _em-dash_, depending how emphatic you wish to be. "I am not {only/just} doing my job; I am making a difference.  "I am not {only/just} doing my job—I am making a difference!

Comment: @BrianHitchcock & up voter: Why do you think "it's better with *also*"?

Comment: Have you checked the various meanings of *but* in a good dictionary? Have you visited our sister site [ell.se]?

Comment: Strictly speaking, it is the word *but* that is dispensable here. Think of it this way, for example: "I am not only doing my job, I am also making a difference." -- Why is it not enough, even without *but*?

Comment: Why is the title about *but* and the body of the question has *but* in all the alternatives? What really is the question?